# Angularjs dir-pagination freeze when data large

Tags: angularjs, html-table, dirpagination

Now I am developing some html pages with angularjs. For table part, I am using dir-pagination to display my data. But now the data is large (around 8000+ rows), when the server return the data, my pages will freeze for 5-10 seconds. So how to solve this problem?

```
<table class="table table-plain ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>Ref no</th>
                                    <th>Amount(RM)</th>
                                </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr dir-paginate="deposit in content | itemsPerPage:10" ng-class="deposit.dt_status == -1 ? 'table-reject' : (deposit.dt_status == 0 ? 'table-pending' : 'table-approve')">
                                    <td>{{deposit.index}}</td>
                                    <td>{{deposit.dt_param5}} <br>
                                        <span style="margin-top: 4px;font-style: italic;">{{deposit.dt_updated_datetime}}</span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>{{deposit.dt_amount}}</td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Have your tried to use | limitTo: <number that you want> ?

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i tried, but still freeze